# ANOVA or any other tests for differences in R

Tags: r, anova, t-test, descriptive-statistics

I have a timecourse dataset consisting of 3 groups of patients as follows:

Group1: control

Group2: Medication A to reduce pain after a medical procedure

Group3: Medication B to reduce pain after a medical procedure

I will like to find out if there are differences between the groups. I wonder if it's correct to carry out the following steps in R:

1. Check normality of data
2. ANOVA
3. pairwise.t.test

I'm not really sure which ANOVA approach to use if data normally distributed/not normally distributed and how to find the differences if any.

I will be happy for some help.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "a timecourse dataset"? Do you have multiple measures per patient over time? Also, is your response variable pain assessed via a 10-point rating?

Comment: Thanks gung. By timecourse I meant a set of time points, and there are multiple measures per patient over time. Although the response variable pain was assessed based on a 10-point rating, I must add that the datasets that I have are measurements of blood hormones and metabolites.

Comment: That makes it much more complicated. How many timepoints do you have? Are all patients measured the same number of times, & at the same points in time? You may need to work w/ a statistical consultant.

Comment: 9 timepoints, and the patients have the same number of measurements and timepoints.